# I want to update values ​in an array in an array while using MongoTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, mongotemplate, criteriaquery

First, I will show the state stored in `mongodb`.

[image]

As you can see, it is a structure with a list called `replies` in a list called `comments`. And inside `replies` there is an array called `likes`.

```
comments : [
    Object1 : {
        replies : [ 
            likes : [
                0 : {},
                1 : {}
            ]
        ]
    },
    Object2 : {
        replies : [
            likes : [
                0 : {},
                1 : {}
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

What I want to do here is to insert/subtract a value only from the `likes` array inside a specific `replies` structure. I'm currently using Spring boot and have tried the following:

```java
        Query query = new Query();
        Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("_id").is(new ObjectId(postId))
                .andOperator(Criteria.where("comments")
                                .elemMatch(Criteria.where("_id").is(new ObjectId(commentId))
                                        .andOperator(Criteria.where("replies")
                                                .elemMatch(Criteria.where("_id").is(new ObjectId(replyId)))
                                        )
                                )
                );

        query.addCriteria(criteria);

        Update update = new Update();
        if (state) {
            // remove user id 
            update.pull("comments.$[].replies.$.likes", new ObjectId(userId));
        } else {
            // add user id 
            update.push("comments.$[].replies.$.likes").value(new ObjectId(userId));
        }
        mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, MyEntity.class);
```

It is an operation to add or remove `userId` according to boolean `state`. As a result of the attempt, up to a specific `comment` is found, but `userId` is unconditionally entered in the first `likes` list of the `replies` list inside the `comment`. What I want is to get into the `likes` list inside a specific `reply`. Am I using the wrong parameter in `update.push()`? I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question as I'm not experienced with spring's criteria builder, but here's how you would do it in mongo directly, which might help you to figure it out:

You could define [arrayfilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-all-documents-that-match-arrayfilters-in-an-array) allowing you to keep track of the corresponding indices of each `comments` and `replies`. You can then use those indices to push a new object at the exact matching indices:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: "<postId>"
},
{
  $push: {
    "comments.$[comments].replies.$[replies].likes": {
      _id: "newlyInsertedLikeId"
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "comments._id": "<commentId>"
    },
    {
      "replies._id": "<replyId>"
    }
  ]
})
```

Here's an example on mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/eNdDXXlyi2X