# How to get particular details from nested object from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I'm saving data for a NestJs based web app in MongoDB.

My MongoDB Data looks like this

```
"gameId": "1a2b3c4d5e"
"rounds": [
    {
      "matches": [
        {
          "match_id": "1111abc1111",
          "team1": {
            "team_id": "team8",
            "score": 0
          },
          "team2": {
            "team_id": "team2",
            "score": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "match_id": "2222abc2222",
          "team1": {
            "team_id": "team6",
            "score": 0
          },
          "team2": {
            "team_id": "team5",
            "score": 0
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Here we have **gameId** for each game and inside each game, there are many rounds and many matches. Each match has **match_id**. How can I get a particular match info and edit it based on **gameId** & **match_id**?
(N.B: I'm willing to update score based on **match_id**)

I've tried something like this

```
    const matchDetails = await this.gameModel.findOne({
      gameId: gameId,
      rounds: { $elemMatch: { match_id: match_id } },
    });
```

But this doesn't work and returns **null**. How to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're applying the `elemMatch` on the `rounds` array, but it should be on `rounds.matches`. Changing your query to the following will fix the problem:

```
const matchDetails = await this.gameModel.findOne({
      gameId: gameId,
      "rounds.matches": { $elemMatch: { match_id: match_id } },
});
```

EDIT:
To only get a specific matching element, you can use a simple aggregation with `$unwind` and `$filter`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "gameId": gameId,
      "rounds.matches": { $elemMatch: { match_id: match_id } }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$rounds"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      match: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$rounds.matches",
          as: "match",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$match.match_id",
              match_id 
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Example on [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XCXiwwfaLOo).

Comment: Doesn't work as expected. Returns all the matches. Not the one with particular match_id

Comment: Wait, you mean you want to only get the matching array element?

Comment: yes. I want only the particular match that matches with the match_id

Comment: Oh ok, see my update.

Comment: This works. Though it became a bit complex than I expected. But does the work. Any Idea how can I update scores inside the teams?

Comment: You could use `arrayfilters` as described here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70020370/3761628). You may want to ask a separate question regarding the update, if you need further help. Please consider upvoting/accepting this one, thanks :)